# Is there a way to configure Libreoffice so that a cell referring to an empty cell also displays an empty cell?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Suppose a Libreoffice spreadsheet involving just two cells, namely A1 and A2, has the string "abc" in cell A1 and "=A1" in cell A2.

```
    |---+------+
    |   |   A  |  (Showing formulas)
    |---+------+
    | 1 | abc  |
    | 2 | =A1  |
    |---+------+
```

Evidently cell A2 will then display the same content of cell A1, namely "abc", as below.

```
    |---+------+
    |   |   A  |  (Showing values)
    |---+------+
    | 1 | abc  |
    | 2 | abc  |
    |---+------+
```

At this point suppose that you delete the content of cell A1, so that A1 becomes empty.  What happens to A2?  Answer: A2 displays the number zero.

```
    |---+------+
    |   |   A  |  (Showing values)
    |---+------+
    | 1 |      |
    | 2 |   0  |
    |---+------+
```

I think this behaviour is unreasonable.  I think A2 should also display nothing!

I thought I could change this by tweaking some configuration and I got as far as the somewhat obscure "Tools - Options - Formula - Details", but it doesn't quite do the job.

Here is a concrete example to support my argument that the standard behavior is indeed unreasonable. Given the spreadsheet:

```
    |---+------+------+------------------|
    |   |   A  |   B  |        C         | (Showing formulas)
    |---+------+------+------------------|
    | 1 |   2  |   4  | =average(A1:B1)  |
    | 2 | =A1  | =B1  | =average(A2:B2)  |
    |---+------+------+------------------|
```

which displays as

```
    |---+---+---+---|
    |   | A | B | C | (Showing values)
    |---+---+---+---|
    | 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
    | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
    |---+---+---+---|
```

suppose that we delete A1.  The table will then display

```
    |---+---+---+---|
    |   | A | B | C | (Showing values)
    |---+---+---+---|
    | 1 |   | 4 | 4 |
    | 2 | 0 | 4 | 2 |
    |---+---+---+---|
```

and I think there is no reason why  C2 should display 2, as it does.  I think it should have the same value as C1, namely 4.  After all, line 2 is essentially trying to replicate line 1.

> Question:    Is there a way to configure Libreoffice so that a cell
> referring to an empty cell also displays an empty cell?

Comment: I cannot believe something so blindingly obvious can be so awkward. If I ask for the value of a cell, that's what I want; not what you think I want. Thank you for asking this question.

Comment: You should give a TED-talk about this behaviour. I have always hated, how Calc displays empty cells as "0" because that is conceptually such a brutalization. I compare "0" to an empty delivery van. And an "empty" cell is when the entire van was stolen from its parking space. There is a difference.

Answer (score 2):

After studying a bit about user defined functions (gently
being pushed to do so by @tohuwawohu), here is my solution, written in a
language I'd have understood before knowing anything about user defined functions, and tested in version 6.0.7.3.

1. Via the menu bar, go to `Tools` - `Macros` - `Organize Macros` - `LibreOffice Basic...`
2. Click on the button marked `Organizer...`
3. On the little window, select the name of your current spreadsheet
4. Click on the button marked `New...`, and type in a name for your Module, say "MyModule" and click `Ok`
5. Back in the window "LibreOffice Basic Macro Organizer", click `Edit`
6. You are now in the IDE (Integrated development environment), where you will define your function.  Begin by clicking anywhere in the big top right window to activate it.
7. Go to the last line and type in:

   ```
   Function id(x)
       id = x
   End Function
   ```

This will create a user-defined function called `id`, which is effectively the identity function.

This is it.  Now, in order to test it, go back to your worksheet window (e.g. via the menu bar option `Window`) and type in the following

```
    |---+---------+---------+-----------------|
    |   |    A    |    B    |       C         | (Showing formulas)
    |---+---------+---------+-----------------|
    | 1 |       2 |       4 | =average(A1:B1) |
    | 2 | =id(A1) | =id(B1) | =average(A2:B2) |
    |---+---------+---------+-----------------|
```

You should be seeing

```
    |---+---+---+---|
    |   | A | B | C | (Showing values)
    |---+---+---+---|
    | 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
    | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
    |---+---+---+---|
```

Now here is the most important part: delete cell A1.  You will then see

```
    |---+---+---+---|
    |   | A | B | C | (Showing values)
    |---+---+---+---|
    | 1 |   | 4 | 4 |
    | 2 |   | 4 | 4 |
    |---+---+---+---|
```

which, I believe,  is the expected behavior!!

---

Conclusion: when you type in `=A1` in cell A2, you do not quite get what
you have in A1.  Libreoffice makes a guess (which I think it shouldn't)
that when A1 is empty, what you really want in A2 is ZERO.

With `=id(A1)` (logically this is indistinguishable from `=A1`) I guess
Libreoffice is somehow prevented from doing any funny interpretation and puts
in A2 exactly what you have in A1, including the case that A1 is empty.

---

Quoting from "Predictably Irrational: The Hidden Forces That Shape Our Decisions ", by Dan Ariely:

“Zero has had a long history. The Babylonians invented the concept of
zero; the ancient Greeks debated it in lofty terms (how could something
be nothing?); the ancient Indian scholar Pingala paired Zero with the
numeral 1 to get double digits; and both the Mayans and the Romans made
Zero a part of their numeral systems. But Zero finally found its place
around AD 498, when the Indian astronomer Aryabhatta sat up in bed one
morning and exclaimed, "Sthanam sthanam dasa gunam" — which translates,
roughly as, "place to place in ten times in value". With that, the idea
of decimal based place value notion was born. Now Zero was on a roll: It
spread to the Arab world, where it flourished; crossed the Iberian
Peninsula to Europe (thanks to the Spanish Moors); got some tweaking
from the Italians; and eventually sailed the Atlantic to the New World,
where zero ultimately found plenty of employment (together with the
digit 1) in a place called Silicon Valley.”

I would humbly add that spreadsheets admit something representing
"nothingness" that is even more ethereal than zero
itself: an empty cell!

Comment: Awesome. I needed this for forms, to be able to print a few blancs for emergencies, where normally the form would hold "month" and "year". You got some small steps missing in your instructions for creating the id-function. And in my Calc (version 7.5) I had followed your instructions, and created "id" but in the main table it will be used as "ID" in capitals. Seems all functions are using capital letters. Thank you for finding and sharing this solution. Stackoverflow does not want "thank you" in comments, but I say this gets more than a simple click.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two alternative ways to handle empty cell references:

### 1. Hide Zero values globally

By default, LibreOffice Calc displays zero values (as `0` or as boolean `FALSE`, depending on cell formatting). You can change this behaviour in Menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `LibreOffice Calc` -> `View`: under `Display`, untick `Zero Values`:

[image]

### 2. Use a formula

While hiding zero values will apply globally to the entire odt file, adapting the formula affects only the cell(s) that reference another cell. Instead of a simple `=A1`, you could use the following:

> `=IF(A1="";""; A1)`

The formula checks if the referenced cell is empty and returns an empty string in this case, otherwise the value of the referenced cell. If the referenced cell is empty, the referencing cell will be empty, too, independtly of the `Show Zero Values` setting.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, but unfortunately none of the suggested methods are entirely satisfactory.  Regarding "hiding zeros", it does not help at all with my "average problem", i.e. cell C2 in my very last table keeps showing the incorrect value 2.  The second suggestion is OK but my actual cell reference looks like =INDEX(INDIRECT($A$1&".A1:P200"),ROW(),COLUMN()), so in order to check for blanks, I have to have =IF(INDEX(INDIRECT($A$1&".A1:P200"),ROW(),COLUMN())="","",INDEX(INDIRECT($A$1&".A1:P200"),ROW(),COLUMN())) which I find unbelievably ugly!

Comment: @Ruy: Ooops - you're right, i didn't test my solution with AVERAGE() (zero value != NULL value...). And the INDEX() formula is indeed ugly. Maybe you should take recourse to a [user-defined function](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/ug/text/scalc/guide/userdefined_function.html) that handles the issue on a "lower" level.

Comment: I have always wanted to learn how to write user defined functions and I guess your comment leaves me no option but to start right now!  Thanks!